# What pair of muscles provides the most power for running?

Tags: running, strength-training, sprinting

Generally alot of muscles are involved when you are running according to Google, but which one provides the most power?

Answer (score 1):

Your **gluteus maximus** (butt) and **quadriceps** (front of your thighs) provide the bulk of the power while sprinting.

Your glutes and quadriceps work to absorb vertical forces and push into the ground to propel your body forward, extending both your knee and hip.  While they work in tandem to produce this power, the gluteus maximus is the more significant of the two muscle groups—to answer your question: the gluteus maximus produces the most power when running.

Hope this helps!